# How to get child propery

Tags: winrt-xaml

ListView Grid.Row="3" x:Name="lstDetail"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}" SelectionMode="None">                                                                                                                                                                       -->

above is the XAML code. I want to get foreground color and
and id. 
like = StackPanel cluster = sender as StackPanel;
       cluster_id = cluster.Tag.ToString();

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it readable? Also it is not clear what exactly you are looking for? How to get properties of listview or properties of child elements of listview?

Comment: Sorry friends but there is no difference between 70* and 7*. I already tried it out